What is the name of a horror movie about small insects that destroyed humanity?
I saw a movie as a child sometime in 1985-1995.
Special features: Insects could gather in a bunch, put on clothes and pretend to be human.
Memorable scene: The survivors are hiding in the last building, on a yellow sunset background.
A man stands in a raincoat, and then crumbles into a pile of insects
I think it's a movie, not a TV series.

It's a bit later than that, and insect-like nanobots rather than actual insects, but was it the Keanu Reeves version of The Day The Earth Stood Still?

I'm not in a position right now where I could add links to enhance an answer, so if somebody else wants to run with this idea, feel free to do so. But what about the movie Mimic?

It's definitely not a mimic, there are big cockroaches, but in this movie they are small. In "the 'day the earth stood still', nanorobots destroyed everything, and in this, only organic matter. The movie is clearly little-known.

The Worm that Walks is a relevant trope, but I'm not finding a match to this on the page.

This is John Carpenter's Prince of Darkness (1987).

A group of graduate students and scientists uncover an ancient canister in an abandoned church, but when they open the container, they inadvertently unleash a strange liquid and an evil force on all humanity.

The film is moreso about Satanic forces than insects, but those forces do exert influence over insects and some people, and the protagonists spend much of the film trapped in a building, due to it being surrounded by such people.
Your memory of the film seems to be primarily based on one specific scene where the protagonists see a colleague of theirs -- Frank Wyndham -- standing outside the window, speaking to them in a strange voice. When they look closer, they see insects crawling all over him and on the ground near him, then his body starts to fall apart and crumple to the ground. Unbeknownst to them, he was killed in an earlier scene, so he was a corpse the whole time here, somehow being propped up by the insects/Satanic forces.
This scene takes place at night, but the protagonists entered the building in the daytime and remained there overnight, so there are scenes in daylight as well.




Aw man... I totally skipped over that one since it wasn't primarily about the insects. :) I did enjoy the film, though.

Can't really go wrong with John Carpenter.
